# Number of cosets in an infinite group

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

When I have a finite group $G$ and some subgroup $H$, Lagrange's Theorem tells me that the number of cosets of $H$ in $G$ is $\frac{|G|}{|H|}$. Is there any analog of this for infinite groups?

For example $3\mathbb{Z}$ has three distinct cosets in $\mathbb{Z}$, which I can tell by just taking a moment to think about it, but I can't see a general approach to deduce anything similar for a infinite group that is not so convenient as $\mathbb{Z}$.

(I suspect the answer to this is no, but references to any relevant theorems would be appreciated)

Comment: What does “something similar” mean, exacty? Certainly, if $[G:H]$ denotes the cardinality of the collection of cosets of $H$ in $G$, then we have $|G|=[G:H]|H|$, but that doesn’t tell you much about $[G:H]$ when $|H|=|G|$ are both infinite.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the equation $|G|=[G:H]|H|$ needs the axiom of choice in general. You could look here and follow links for more information about that. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001438/is-the-axiom-of-choice-needed-to-prove-g-h-times-h-g